# Power Automate Flows missing in Dynamics365?

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, power-automate

I have a PowerShell script to get information on Power Automate Flows. I learned that some of the flows do not have a WorkflowID (or workflowentityid). The failing ones seem random. They're in different environments, enabled and disabled, and have different creators/owners.

I went to view the CRM table (? I'm new to this IT area, so please pardon any wrong terminology) at `https://myenvironment.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/workflows` and these flows aren't in this table. I am very confused. Any advice?

Troubleshooting Script:

```
$Flowids = $null
$NOids=$null
$NOids=@()
$flowids = @()
$flowarray = $null
$flowarray = @()
$environment = Get-FlowEnvironment -EnvironmentName Default-d67fa8sd7f-e8f76ds7sa-98ds7f-98af7

        $flows = get-adminflow -EnvironmentName $environment.environmentname 
        Foreach($flow in $flows)
                        {
                           Get-AdminFlow -EnvironmentName $environment.environmentname -FlowName $flow.flowname
                           $Result = New-object PSOBJECT
                           $result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Name" -value $flow.DisplayName
                           $result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "workflowid" -value $flow.internal.properties.workflowentityid
                           $flowarray += $result
                           if($flow.internal.properties.workflowentityid -ne $null)
                            {
                                $Flowids += $flow.internal.properties.workflowentityid
                            }
                         if($flow.internal.properties.workflowentityid -eq $null)
                            {
                                $NOids += $flow.displayname
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have all or most of your cloud flows added in solution or in envorinment, you can go make.powerapps.com and then select your enviornment and then default solution, there you will file clouds flows section and you should be able to find most of your flows.

Another way would be to visit
https://emea.flow.microsoft.com/ and then select your environment and there in you could find your flows, provided the user you are logging is either owner or flow is shared with logged in user.

Comment: I can access the flows through the GUI as you described. As far as I know, you cannot view the workflow ID through those pages, as they are not the same as the Flow ID. Please correct me if I'm wrong though! The problem is that I need to access this information in PowerShell as part of a larger script.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the below PS snippet for getting all PA flows. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-powershell?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#display-all-flows)

```
Get-AdminFlow
```

Though the `Workflow` table has the [ability to store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/reference/workflow?view=dataverse-latest&WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422) the Cloud flows, not sure about the parity. It has some known [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/solutions-overview?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#known-limitations) around solution aware flows, where it was started developed in first place. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/create-flow-solution?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422)

Comment: Sadly, this is the PS command I am using already. I'll add that code to the post as well.

Comment: @JuTrust, so what’s the problem now with that PS?

Comment: I can find all of the flows, but a large portion of them do not have a workflow entity ID

Comment: @JuTrust after that what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Essentially, I need the workflow ID because I can use it to pull the CRM entity of the flow. That entity has information I need for documentation purposes, specifically the xml of the flow, which I can't get with Get-Adminflow.
Flows can also be a part of a solution., but solutions reference flows by their Workflow ID. I need the ID to cross-reference it with my solutions to find matches